# May I run Parameter Server separated?

Tags: ros, parameter, server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everybody:
Does there any way to separate Parameter Server from roscore, and run alone!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245696/may-i-run-parameter-server-separated?/) by [Damo](https://answers.ros.org/users/26732/damo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2016-10-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dimitri Schachmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/22775/dimitri-schachmann/) on 2016-10-14**:
May I ask what you would gain from running them separatly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm no expert and it's hard to prove a negative, but I think it is not possible. I conclude so by briefly examining the source code for rosmaster and rosparam:

- [rosparam](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/530cd5339540b80ce727067f3ce6b0799a343318/tools/rosmaster/src/rosmaster/paramserver.py)
- [rosmaster](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/530cd5339540b80ce727067f3ce6b0799a343318/tools/rosmaster/src/rosmaster/master_api.py)

As far as I see there is no server code in the rosparam implementation, but just the dictionary logic. The server stuff is in the rosmaster code. See Line 324.

---

Originally posted by [Dimitri Schachmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/22775/dimitri-schachmann/) with karma: 789 on 2016-10-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1